# Functions allowed in Hilbert and Banach spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have read the following link but could not resolve the question I want to ask. Sorry if it is obvious, but I would appreciate if my doubt is cleared.

[Comparing Hilbert spaces and Banach spaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472134/comparing-hilbert-spaces-and-banach-spaces)

Can I also think of difference of spaces as difference of functions allowed? Therefore, the kind of functions allowed in the Hilbert space, which is $l^2$  is also allowed in $l^p$ spaces where $p$ can be any real number. In a particular problem of estimating a function if we want to look for a class of function within the set allowed by $l^2$ then Hilbert space is fine on the other hand if our problem can have solution which can take allowable function from all $l^p$ spaces then we must work on Banach space.

If the above is true can I ask help in geometrically visualize the functions allowed in Banach space but not in Hilbert space?

Comment: Hilbert spaces and Banach spaces are both very general definitions, they are not always a set of functions, so that is not the correct imagination for Hilbert/Banach spaces.

Comment: @supinf may I request for an attribute of space which shows that it cannot be represented as a set of functions. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces are not simply sets of functions, but sets equipped with a structure of vector space and a further function (a norm for Banach spaces and an inner product for Hilbert spaces) that has important algebraic and topological properties. In particular a Banach space become naturally a metric space and is complete in the topology induced by this metric. An Hilbert space is a space where we can define orthogonality and where any bounded linear functionals can be expressed as an inner product with a well defined and unique vector ( Riesz Representation Theorem).

We know that a Hilbert space is always a Banach space, but the converse is not true. This means that any inner product induce a norm, but a norm can be derived by an inner product only if his norm verifies the parallelogram low:
$$
||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2=2||x||^2+2||y||^2
$$
So, given the same vector space $V$ of functions, we can have a norm on it such that $V$ is a Banach space but not an Hilbert space but we can have a different norm such that $V$ is an Hilbert space.

As an example let $C[0,1]$ the vector space of continuous real functions on $[0,1]$ with the usual pointwise sum and scalar product.
With the sup-norm 
$$ ||f||_\infty=\sup _{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)| $$
it is a Banach space but not an Hilbert space ( to show this test the parallelogram equality with the two functions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1$).But with the norm 
$$
||f||_2=\left( \int_0^1|f(x)|^2dx  \right)^{1/2}
$$
 it become an Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Please bear with me: My problem is; I still cannot understand what goes wrong if I try to think of space as a set of allowable function. This may be equivalent to comparison between structure and allowable set of functions. What is lost if we think it is set of allowable function. Allowable functions may be infinite. I can understand what is being said but cannot prove what I am looking for. May be I should have asked the question differently. How to prove that a space is not a set of allowable functions

Comment: You can think to a set of allowable functions, e.g. the set of all functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, but this is not a space if you does not define a sum operation and a product by a scalar. In other words, a vector space is not a set of function, but a quadruple $S,K,+,\cdot$ where $S$ is the set of functions , $K$ is a field, and $+,\cdot$ are well defined operations. For a Banach or Hilbert space other properties are required for the norm or the inner product, that can be or not satisfied by the elements of $S$, and this depend by the definition of the norm or of the inner product.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment make my question more clearer: I assumed the above and the question is what is the different between one space to other? Is it not the set of allowable functions? I have this (may be wrong) conviction by comparing Sobolev space and Hilbert space. In Sobolev spaces  weakly differential functions are allowed but not in Hilbert space.  This clarification would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the functions of $S$ have weak derivatives and are integrable then you can use this set to construct $L^p$ spaces defining the appropriate norm, or a Sobolev space using a different norm. But I think that it's better if you ask this as another question.

Comment: Thank you and Sorry, I did not understand which question you want to ask separately?  The question comparing Sobolev space and Hilbert space or in general that difference between two spaces is the functions allowed in the two spaces? I shall ask if you kindly clarify.

Comment: About Sobolev and Hilbert spaces.

Comment: I tried but the question was not well taken so I deleted it. I still did not understand what I am missing.

Comment: Finally after so long, I understood and you were explaining perfectly, I did not understand,

Answer (score 1):

Banach space geometry is extremely complicated in general. And there remain many open questions. [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824765540) is a book that discusses in general what kind of geometry unit sphere's can have in Banach spaces. Some of it is pretty straightforward. Some of it is insanely counter-intuitive. I've been told that reflexive Banach spaces are somewhat less terrifying, although I don't know if I totally believe that.

(You probably don't have to pay $80 for it... I'm sure there are other ways to obtain books.)

Hilbert space geometry is a little nicer. There is a notion of perpendicular. So many analogues from $\mathbb{R}^n$ still make sense. In particular, one can ask about the angle between two vectors using the inner product.